# MySQL Error: Unknown column in 'field list' error

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I have a problem with MySQL, i'm trying to insert data in a table but it's returning this error message

> Fatal error: SQL: SELECT e.idtarea AS 'idTarea', e.detalle AS
>   'detalle', e.precio AS 'precio', e.idOrdenReparacion AS
>   'idOrdenReparacion', `e.fecha` AS 'fecha', concat( 'Editar ',
>   'Eliminar' ) AS Opciones FROM Tarea e WHERE e.idtarea like '%%' ORDER
>   BY e.idtarea;, Error: Unknown column 'e.fecha' in 'field list' in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/scep/tareas.php on line 75

**Here is my code:**

```
    $SQL="

      SELECT 
        e.idtarea AS 'idTarea', 
        e.detalle AS 'detalle', 
        e.precio AS 'precio', 
        e.idOrdenReparacion AS 'idOrdenReparacion', 
        e.fecha AS 'fecha', 
        concat('<a href=\'editarTarea.php?id=',e.idtarea,'\'>Editar</a>&nbsp;','<a href=\'eliminarTarea.php?id=',e.idtarea,'\' onclick=javascript:confirm(\'Eliminar?>\')>Eliminar </a>') AS Opciones 
      FROM Tarea e ".$FILTRAR_POR." 
      ORDER BY e.idtarea;";

      $RESULT = mysql_query($SQL) or trigger_error("SQL: $SQL, Error: " . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

**Table Tarea from database:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tarea` (
   `idTarea` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `detalle` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `precio` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `idOrdenReparacion` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idTarea`,`idOrdenReparacion`),
   KEY `fk_Tarea_OrdenReparacion1_idx` (`idOrdenReparacion`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_danish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

.....

  ALTER TABLE `Tarea`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Tarea_OrdenReparacion1` FOREIGN KEY (`idOrdenReparacion`) 
  REFERENCES `OrdenReparacion` (`idOrdenReparacion`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: it mean you have not any colon with the name  `e.fecha`

Comment: Just to clarify, are you really trying to insert data here?

Comment: yes fecha is Data type, i want to use e.fecha to display it in a table later... I use e.idtarea to edit the table by editarTarea.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that a previous version of the table didn't exist where the column didn't exist?  If there was already a version of the table, then your SQL will not made changes to the columns in the table.

Comment: Hmmm I add fecha column by phpMyAdmin then I make a dump

Comment: Another thing to try is see if the command runs when you remove that from the select list.  Sometimes I've seen another error cause weird issues to appear that look valid.  If you still get an error, but it simply changes when you remove that field from the selection list, then something else may be up.

Comment: I did that, this fix the error, but it does not display any of the other values ​​in the table. btw I need to show the fecha column. i'm really confused

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same DB that you connected to in PHPMyAdmin?  If you are expecting results to be returned when the query runs and you are not getting any results, then it sounds like maybe you might be running against an outdated version of your DB.  Did you possibly create a second database with a different name at some point, but similar table structure?

Comment: Yes I edited the table by mysql console and it worked, the db was te same (that's weird), maybe something wrong went on phpMyAdmin so for the later modifications i will use the console directly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Np, glad it worked out.  It's always frustrating trying to rundown problems like that.  My best tool I've found is to just keep checking assumptions until you find the one that is incorrect. Experience lends itself to knowing the common ones.  (And yes, I still make them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fieldnames and aliases must be enclosed in backticks, not in single quotes as you did. Updated query:

```
$SQL="SELECT 
    e.idtarea AS `idTarea`, 
    e.detalle AS `detalle`, 
    e.precio AS `precio`, 
    e.idor AS `idOrdenReparacion`, 
    e.fecha AS `fecha`, 
    concat('<a href=\'editarTarea.php?id=',e.idtarea,'\'>Editar</a>&nbsp;','<a href=\'eliminarTarea.php?id=',e.idtarea,'\' onclick=javascript:confirm(\'Eliminar?>\')>Eliminar </a>') AS Opciones 
  FROM Tarea e ".$FILTRAR_POR." 
  ORDER BY e.idtarea;";
```

Comment: What does `echo $SQL;` display?